# MongoDB incorrect BSON document format

Tags: java, mongodb, bson, mongo-java-driver

I was trying to get the BSON document out of the MongoDB. As per the https://www.mongodb.com/json-and-bson , i am expecting the document received from the driver as :

```
{"hello": "world"} →
\x16\x00\x00\x00           // total document size
\x02                       // 0x02 = type String
hello\x00                  // field name
\x06\x00\x00\x00world\x00  // field value
\x00                       // 0x00 = type EOO ('end of object')
```

But i see it in readable json format.

The data inserted in MongoDB:

> db.test.insert({"hello": "world"})

Sample code:

```
    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients
            .create("mongodb://localhost:27018/admin");
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("MYTEST");
    MongoCollection<Document> coll = database.getCollection("testarr");
    Publisher<Document> publisher = coll.find();
    MongoDBObservableSubscriber<Document> subscriber = null;
    subscriber = new MongoDBObservableSubscriber<Document>();
    publisher.subscribe(subscriber);
    Queue<Document> mongoCursor = subscriber.getResults();
    while (true) {
        if (!mongoCursor.isEmpty()) {
            Document document = mongoCursor.poll();
            if (document != null) {
                System.out.println("==========");
                System.out.println("actual document -> "+document);
                System.out.println("Bson document->"+document.toBsonDocument());
                System.out.println("Json document->"+document.toJson(JsonWriterSettings.builder().outputMode(JsonMode.EXTENDED).build()));
                RawBsonDocument raw = RawBsonDocument.parse(document.toJson(JsonWriterSettings.builder().outputMode(JsonMode.EXTENDED).build()));
                System.out.println("raw document ->"+raw);
                
                final BsonDocument ceDoc = document.toBsonDocument();
                final OutputBuffer outputBuffer = new BasicOutputBuffer();
                final BsonWriter innerWriter = new BsonBinaryWriter(outputBuffer);
                BsonDocumentCodec bsonDocumentCodec= new BsonDocumentCodec();
                bsonDocumentCodec.encode(innerWriter, ceDoc, EncoderContext.builder().build());
                final BsonBinary encoded = new BsonBinary(outputBuffer.toByteArray());
                System.out.println("Encoded->"+encoded.toString());
                Bson bsonObject =BsonDocument.parse(document.toJson(JsonWriterSettings.builder().outputMode(JsonMode.EXTENDED).build()));
                System.out.println("bsonObject->"+bsonObject);
                System.out.println("==========");
            }
        }
    }
```

output:

```
actual document -> Document{{_id=618b9c31759ba7a2fa73094c, hello=world}}
Bson document->{"_id": {"$oid": "618b9c31759ba7a2fa73094c"}, "hello": "world"}
Json document->{"_id": {"$oid": "618b9c31759ba7a2fa73094c"}, "hello": "world"}
raw document ->{"_id": {"$oid": "618b9c31759ba7a2fa73094c"}, "hello": "world"}
Encoded->BsonBinary{type=0, data=[39, 0, 0, 0, 7, 95, 105, 100, 0, 97, -117, -100, 49, 117, -101, -89, -94, -6, 115, 9, 76, 2, 104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 0, 0]}
bsonObject->{"_id": {"$oid": "618b9c31759ba7a2fa73094c"}, "hello": "world"}
```

In non of the ways,  I see output in actual BSON format[as below one.]

```
\x16\x00\x00\x00           // total document size
\x02                       // 0x02 = type String
hello\x00                  // field name
\x06\x00\x00\x00world\x00  // field value
\x00                       // 0x00 = type EOO ('end of object')
```

Is there are away to derive the BSON format.

Comment: every time you cast a bson object to a string (when you println) it will serialize as json.  The data is there and correct, seen in the Encoded BsonBinary printing.  It doesn't match the documentation because mongoldb added an ObjectID field (type 7).  Later you see 2,104,101,108,108, 111,0 which is "hello" followed by a null followed by 6,0,0,0,119,111,114,108,100,0 which matches what you showed for \x06\x00\x00\x00world\x00 followed by a null.   What are you confused about?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you do a println, you're are implicitly casting the object to a string.

MongoDB-Java-Driver performs string casting by converting the BSON to the JSON representation, which you are seeing.

```java
System.out.println("Bson document->"+document.toBsonDocument());
//----------------------------------^ this concatenation turns the bson 
//                                  object to the string representation (JSON)
```

The encoded BSON correctly shows the true BSON

I think you're confused because MongoDB automatically applies an ObjectID to any objects that are inserted to the database.  This ObjectID is **not** part of the BSON standard, and therefore not documented on the BSON specification. However, since you're pulling data from MongoDB, you're seeing it.

Had you locally generated the BSON and parsed it, you would not see the ObjectID

```-java
Encoded->BsonBinary{type=0, data=[39, 0, 0, 0, 7, 95, 105, 100, 0, 97, -117, -100, 49, 117, -101, -89, -94, -6, 115, 9, 76, 2, 104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 0, 0]}
```

Parsing this out per the documentation

Notice your size is 39 (bigger than example) because MongoDB added the ObjectID to the document.

The latter half of the document has the key/value in it as you expect
`\x02hello\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00world\x00`

```
\x39\x00\x00\x00           // total document size
7                          // 0x07 = type objectID
95,105,100,0               // field name = "_id" null terminated
97,-117,-100,49,117,-101,-89,-94,-6,115,9,76   // The objectID in bin format                 
\x02                       // 0x02 = type String
hello\x00                  // field name
\x06\x00\x00\x00world\x00  // field value
\x00                       // 0x00 = type EOO ('end of object')
```

Comment: Thanks Bauman.  After encoding it was able to get BSON.

Comment: I was using the below steps to encode.BasicOutputBuffer outputBuffer = new BasicOutputBuffer();
BsonBinaryWriter writer = new BsonBinaryWriter(outputBuffer);
DOCUMENT_CODEC.encode(writer, document, EncoderContext.builder().isEncodingCollectibleDocument(true).build());
RawBsonDocument raw = new RawBsonDocument(outputBuffer.toByteArray());   Is there any better way.